# Access address bar through chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This question maybe too much but still, is there any way I can add a extra item in addressbar context menu ?.. Like after "Edit Search Engines" I want to add extra menu Item through my extension ? 
[image]

Can't find anything in doc's.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus

Comment: @Rob yes I can access my context menu every where but not in address bar. I didn't find any way to define access to addressbar in manifest also.

Comment: Look at the examples: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:omnibox